# Session becomes invalid after timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have an MobileFirst Platform 6.3 app that uses Adapter Authentication.  The user must be able to login and logout multiple times within a session, switching credentials (i.e login as "userA", logout, login as "userB", logout, etc.).  All this works fine as long as the session stays active.

If I put my app in the background for 20-30 minutes, I will see in my server logs that my `logout-function` (onLogout) was called.  I'm assuming this is being called by the framework when the session times out.  My onLogout calls `WL.Server.setActiveUser("RealmName", null)` so this should invalidate the session, which it does seem to do.

The problem comes in when the user brings the app back to the foreground and attempts to invoke a protected procedure.  I see by the server log that my `login-function` (onAuthRequired) is invoked by the framework.  The message parameter is undefined.  The headers parameter contains something like

```
{"Cookie":["WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE=5a39bf15-b217-40c2-97eb-c6622213e799; JSESSIONID=00003dozYVeiAYXJYzoQf_oG6BI:5702d236-4455-4e22-bf0c-132459018524"],"Host":["192.168.1.64:10080"],"WL-Instance-Id":["4rjpubf76afnvs9l61gtkf197t"],"X-Requested-With":["XMLHttpRequest"],"Content-Length":["198"],"x-wl-clientlog-deviceId":["DE67FB50-5ABD-4418-A39D-69058144454F"],"x-wl-clientlog-model":["iPad5,4"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508/Worklight/6.3.0.0 (358300384)"],"x-wl-clientlog-osversion":["8.2"],"x-wl-clientlog-appname":["Greenwell"],"Connection":["keep-alive"],"x-wl-device-id":["B405CAA3-4EE6-4581-9004-5AA8AA950E0A"],"x-wl-clientlog-appversion":["1.2.1"],"x-wl-app-version":["1.2.1"],"Accept-Language":["en-US"],"x-wl-analytics-tracking-id":["5A9D03E9-42FA-41E7-9FFD-69C4EE89EF95"],"Authorization":["{\"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm\":{\"ID\":{\"token\":\"q0dhk0eutb0gi53ak2mltrlbkv\",\"app\":{\"id\":\"GreenwellBanking\",\"version\":\"1.2.1\"},\"device\":{\"id\":\"B405CAA3-4EE6-4581-9004-5AA8AA950E0A\",\"os\":\"8.2\",\"model\":\"iPad5,4\",\"environment\":\"ipad\"},\"custom\":{}}}}"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate"],"x-wl-app-details":["{\"applicationDetails\":{\"platformVersion\":\"6.3.0.0\",\"nativeVersion\":\"1889110191\",\"skinName\":\"default\",\"skinChecksum\":2615010882,\"skinLoaderChecksum\":\"(null)\"}}"],"Content-Type":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"],"Accept":["text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*"],"x-wl-clientlog-env":["ipad"]}.
```

Neither the success handler nor the failure handler of the `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` call get invoked.  There seems to be a response in the log showing authRequired: true.

```
2015-03-25 10:44:16.937 Greenwell[649:305965] [DEBUG] [NONE] fetching offers
2015-03-25 10:44:16.964 Greenwell[649:305965] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/GreenwellBanking/ipad/query]
2015-03-25 10:44:16.967 Greenwell[649:305968] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:37 :: Request url is http://192.168.1.64:10080/GreenwellBanking/apps/services/api/GreenwellBanking/ipad/query
2015-03-25 10:44:16.977 Greenwell[649:305968] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:182 :: Starting the request with URL http://192.168.1.64:10080/GreenwellBanking/apps/services/api/GreenwellBanking/ipad/query
2015-03-25 10:44:17.116 Greenwell[649:286631] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:195 :: Request Success
2015-03-25 10:44:17.119 Greenwell[649:286631] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:196 :: Response Status Code : 200
2015-03-25 10:44:17.122 Greenwell[649:286631] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:197 :: Response Content : /*-secure-
{"errorMessage":null,"isSuccessful":true,"authRequired":true}*/
```

**challengeHandler**

```
var challengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("CaasAuthRealm");

challengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
    if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
        return false;
    }
   if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

challengeHandler.handleChallenge = function (response) {
    var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

    console.log("Handling Challenge - authRequired = " + authRequired);

    if (authRequired) {
        challengeHandler.submitFailure("Bad credentials");

        $.mobile.changePage("login.html", {transition: "slide"});

    } else {

        challengeHandler.submitSuccess();

        if (Model.getInstance().username == "wcmaas-anonymous") {
            $.mobile.changePage( "landing.html", { transition: "flip", reverse: true } );
        } else {
            $.mobile.changePage( "home.html", { transition: "flip" } );
        }

    }
}
```

Questions:

1. If `onAuthRequired` is invoked by the framework on the server when the app calls `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`, why am I not seeing a challenge issued to the app?  If I did, I could prompt the user to log in again.
2. Am I misunderstanding how a timeout should be handled?  It seems like I am properly invalidating the session in `onLogout`, but how can I prompt the user to reauthenticate without a Challenge?

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably using adapter authentication and forgot to use  submitSuccess() in your challenge handler. Can you provide more details about your authentication config and paste the challenge handler code?

Comment: you are correct.  I am using Adapter Authentication and my handleChallenge does not use submitSuccess().  I actually commented it out because I found that submitSuccess was causing my submitAuthentication to be invoked twice, resulting in the error `Cannot change identity of an already logged in user`.  I edited the question to include my challengeHandler with submitSuccess() added back in, but I just confirmed that it reintroduces the problem of submitting authentication twice.  Perhaps I caused one problem by trying to fix another when I removed it.